# Possible to Export IIS ip bindings using Powershell ? no seperate module installed

Tags: iis, powershell, export

I saw some approaches to find domains bound to ip and port using powershell + a custom modul.

Is there a way to do it without installing anything else besides powershell v. 2.0 ?

What I need is public ip adress + ports used for a website which is hosted by iis.

Any Ideas? Maybe there is even an export/import function inside of iis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the bindings like this:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Get-WebBinding
```

Comment: Although this doesn't meet the original request of not having a custom module, I believe that if you have IIS 7.5 or greater installed then you will also have the module.

Comment: Import-Module was introduced in V3.  V1 and V2 were limited to snapins.

Comment: I can run the command on Windows Server 2008 R2 machines, which I haven't upgraded to V3.

Comment: Hmm.  I might be wrong about that.  Relying on this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849725.aspx which only shows V3 under Other Versions.

Comment: @mjolinor I think you are mistaken, as Import-Module is available in v2 (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849725(v=wps.620).aspx)

Comment: @mjolinor You should see that if you select other versions and choose v3 you will see it also applies to v2.

Comment: Silly me, I expected it to be listed in the drop-down as an Other Verson.

Comment: absolutely perfect, sir. Thank you

Comment: on one server using ps3.0 it couldn't load the module. Maybe outgoing calls are not allowed here. Don't know any other reason.